# Windows Server 2008 as Bridge in virtualbox: make another Virtual Machine enter his Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, virtualbox

I have installed a Windows Server 2008 in Virtualbox(bridge) this one work fantastic! i want to make a virtual machine(virtualbox) which can enter the Domain and access my Server 2008(Datacenter).

1. Which network connection should i choose? bridge, nat, host-only?
2. How should i configure Server 2008 to accepts the new machine in his Domain?

Thank you a lot!

**Edit :** When i mean enter the Domain it is like this explicitly  :

1. I just want to build into VirtualBox a LAN Environment -> with One Server and One another OS.
2. On the Server(win2k8) i will install a Webservice( with Windows Authentication )
3. On the OS a client which should consumes the Webservice.

This is why the client should be a part of the win2k8 Domain 'cause the authentication.

I hope that was clear enough.

Comment: So is the current WIn2k8 guest a domain controller?

Comment: Yes it is a domain controller!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second host to only access the guest DC, I suggest you create a Host-only network in VBox, add a second NIC to the DC and attach it to the new network.  Then connect the NIC of the new guest to host-only network.

If you don't care if both hosts have access to the bridged network, then add the second guest to the bridged network but point it to the DC for DNS.

Having the server and the guest point to an AD DNS will be crucial to make this work

Comment: well! thank you a lot uSlackr! my Win2k8 is the DataCenter Edition! so i think he is a domain controller isnt? I tried Host-Only but i occur some problems that is why i made a bridge for my Server! do u mean that i must installed a new VirtualBox into Win2k8 and then installed Win 7 into it?

Comment: It is not a domain controller unless you install the bits and run dcpromo.  but it doesn't sound like you need it.  I just wasn't sure.  And no, there is no reason to change your current setup.  Perhaps you could clarify what you mean when you say you want a second host to "enter the domain"